# How do I restore the main toolbar in Adobe Fireworks CS6 on Mac?

Tags: macos, adobe-fireworks

My main toolbar in Fireworks CS6 on Mac went away. I'm referring to the one that has the un-do, re-do, import/export, save, bring to front, etc. type icons.

For the life of me, I cannot find an option to bring it back, including right-clicking in/near the toolbar that still displays (the one with the hand tool, zoom tool, Bridge icon).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Fireworks CS6 documentation the toolbar is only available on Windows.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I noticed it missing after I switched from Windows to Mac and didn't realize it doesn't exist in Mac.